# mysqlclient pip failure on Linux

Tags: python, mysql, linux, django

I'm working on a Python3.4/Django project (on CentOS 6.8x64) and am trying to install the mysqlclient driver. Despite hours of googling I can't figure out how to sort out what looks like a compile error during install.

As far as I can tell I have all the necessary library packages installed but so far no luck. Here's the output (sorry for the verbosity):

```
$ sudo pip3 install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.10.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.4 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-qqqgbh_2/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-cwqrqsw1-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
    gcc -pthread -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,3,10,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.10 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_mysql.o
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_ping’:
    _mysql.c:1911: error: ‘MYSQL’ has no member named ‘reconnect’
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3.4 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-qqqgbh_2/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-cwqrqsw1-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-qqqgbh_2/mysqlclient/
```

Comment: This seems like a library compatibility thing to me. Is it possible that I need an older version of mysqlclient?

Answer (score 0):

i guess you need to install mysql-devel or mariadb-devel (if that is already available on centos 6) in order to compile.

```
yum install mysql-devel
```

Comment: I thought maybe that was it too but I already have it installed (MariaDB-devel.x86_64)

Comment: I thought the same, I am having the problem with MariaDB. I've got the following install from a MariaDB perspective...

    $ sudo dnf list installed | grep "maria"

    mariadb mariadb-common mariadb-config mariadb-devel mariadb-errmsg mariadb-libs mariadb-server  mariadb-server-utils

Comment: Many of those I don't even see listed in the repo. I thought I added the standard one from the MariaDB website. Did you have to add another?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a compatibility problem between mysqlclient and the latest version of MariaDB (10.2). I adjusted my package repo to point to older versions of MariaDB (10.0 or 10.1) and installed one of those then mysqlclient built and installed without issue.